# IIF statement to determine visibility of ImageButton in GridView not evaluating properly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, iif

I have a GridView that displays user info along with two template fields with imagebuttons. One is to open up a detailsview to edit user information. The other is to edit the user's password.

In my Code Behind, I have 3 IIf statements that check for certain criteria. Based on certain combinations of this criteria, I want the ImageButtons to either show/not show appropriately.

Here is my code behind:

```
Protected Sub gvUsers_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvUsers.RowDataBound

    Dim isProvisioned As Boolean
    Dim acceptedToS As Boolean
    Dim isSuspended As Boolean


    'hide password change option for users that have not yet been provisioned or have not accepted ToS Agreement or have been suspended'
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow And _
        DirectCast(sender, GridView).EditIndex <> e.Row.DataItemIndex Then

        isProvisioned = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.DataItem(GUser.columns.DATEADDED).ToString), False, True)
        acceptedToS = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.DataItem(GUser.columns.TOSTIMESTAMP).ToString), False, True)
        isSuspended = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.DataItem(GUser.columns.SUSPENDDATE).ToString), False, True)

        Dim btnAdminEdit As ImageButton = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("btnAdminEdit"), ImageButton)
        Dim btnAdminSelect As ImageButton = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("btnAdminSelect"), ImageButton)

        btnAdminEdit.Visible = Not (isSuspended) AndAlso isProvisioned AndAlso acceptedToS 
        btnAdminSelect.Visible = isProvisioned

    Else
        gvUsers.EmptyDataText = "No records found matching specified criteria."
    End If

End Sub
```

I don't know what changed because this code DID work at one point. However, when I test the page, both imagebuttons seem to show up no matter what. While debugging, I also saw that it seemed to "evaluate" each row the same way. As in, for each row that went through my IIf statements, it always returned the same values, even if it was not true.

I have a hunch that it's taking the first row's values and reusing it some how, or evaluating the same row; that's why it always returns the same values and always shows the imagebuttons, even though they are not supposed to be visible according to my IIf statements.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm not too sure how to resolve it from here.

Comment: I would check your data.  Perhaps this is correct, and something has caused all of your data to be updated to the same values.

Comment: Can we see the code you use to databind your GridView?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after delving a little deeper, I found what was causing the problem.

The last change I made before seeing this problem was the addition of another column to be displayed in the GridView. This distorted the index of the columns so my IIF statements were not checking the correct datafields and thus, were evaluating incorrectly.

So, the code behind I posted does work and luckily proved that I wasn't going crazy. The logic is correct!

Thanks to those who took time to glance at this question!